# How can I load blender files with wavefront?

Tags: python, pyglet, wavefront

I am trying to load obj files with wavefront. I failed while I selected file as obj file. I tried mtl and the 3d model didn't loaded. Code I just used:

```
kup = pywavefront.Wavefront("ichigo/kup.obj")
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    visualization.draw(küp)
```

I tried with the name "kup.obj" but problem didn't fixed.
I downloaded some 3D objects from a site. but problem is not about file.

Comment: maybe the umlaut in the obj filename is a problem. try renaming it to something without umlauts, e.g. `kuep.obj`.

Comment: I tried exporting file with his own name in blender. And program succesfully ran. but   the 3d model didn't loaded again.

Comment: Any error messages? Did you try without the special characters as Alexander asked?

Comment: positive. I tried with the name kup.obj. but the problem is still living